# expected class-name before '(' token ~GameC()

Tags: c++

**I am still learning c++ and SDL2**

I am trying to compile this code and i am having some 
 trouble with it.

**Trouble:**
when I try to compile my code i get this error:

expected class-name before '(' token ~GameC()

I was trying to learn about constructors and destructors 
**Here is my code**:

**game.hpp**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>


class Game
{
public:

    GameC();
    ~GameC();
    SDL_Renderer *render;
    SDL_Window *window;
    
    SDL_Event event;


    bool running = true;

    static void Draw(SDL_Renderer *render, SDL_Texture *texture, SDL_Rect rSR, SDL_Rect rDr){}
};
```

**game.cpp**

```cpp
#include "game.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Game::GameC(){

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0){
        std::cout << "SDLFailed to init() :- " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tgame", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 800, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    
    while (running){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
            }
        }       

        SDL_RenderClear(render);

        SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }
}


Game::~GameC(){
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(render);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "src/game.hpp"

// libs 
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDl_image.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    
    Game game;

    return 0;
}
```

I am still learning c++. **Please help me!!**

Comment: The contructor and destructor must have the same name as the class.

Comment: `class Game` and then constructor `GameC()` and destructor `~GameC()`

Answer (score 1):

There are few *special* functions in class declaration that must have same name as class:

- Constructor (default, with parameters etc.)
- Destructor
- Copy constructor
- Move constructor

In your class `Game`, constructor's and destructor's names are `GameC`. Simply, change their name to `Game` to fix error.